# Extracting data from Family Tree Maker into spreadsheet?

Tags: family-tree-maker

Is there a way to download the data on all people in a family tree from Family Tree Maker (I'm using version 2012 on PC, file format is .ftmb) so that the data can be seen in a spreadsheet (including dob, dom, dod, spouse, etc)?

This would be very useful for checking data, statistical analysis, etc.

Comment: My Heritage Family tree Builder instructs the user to locate the csv file in the Reports

Answer (score 5):

If you're willing to export to GEDCOM as Colin suggests, another option would be to use the free [Family Tree Builder program from MyHeritage](https://www.myheritage.com/family-tree-builder).

Family Tree Builder has a specific report to export all or selected people and all or selected fields to a csv (comma delimited file) that spreadsheet programs will open:

[image]

The resulting information will look like this:

[image]

Credit: The screenshots are from the July 17, 2018 MyHeritage Webinar: [Everything you need to know about Genealogical Charts and Reports](https://familytreewebinars.com/download.php?webinar_id=810) by Uri Gonen, MyHeritage Product Manager

Answer (score 3):

There is an online help page titled [Save a chart or report as an external file in Family Tree Maker](https://support.mackiev.com/717380-Save-a-chart-or-report-as-an-external-file-in-Family-Tree-Maker) that says under **Saving a report as a file** that you can use the Share button to:

> **Export to CSV**: This format organizes information into fields (comma-separated values) and is meant to be imported into spreadsheet
>   programs. Only reports that use column formats can be exported to CSV.

As commented by @lkessler:

> Different reports give different data. The Person Custom Report will
>   give Birth, Marriage, Death dates and places along with Facts and
>   Notes, but not the spouse's name. The Person List of Individuals
>   report will give the birth, marriage and death dates along with the
>   spouse's name, but not the places. No report gives everything, but
>   each report gives something useful.

Comment: Yes, that will work. Different reports give different data. The Person Custom Report will give Birth, Marriage, Death dates and places along with Facts and Notes, but not the spouse's name. The Person List of Individuals report will give the birth, marriage and death dates along with the spouse's name, but not the places. No report gives everything, but each report gives something useful.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this is to export as a Gedcom and then use the old but still working programme GedXlate available from [GedMagic](http://www.gedmagic.com/gedxlate.htm). This will include spouses and you can configure which columns that you want in your spreadsheet.

Comment: In the interest of better readability, I edited your link title so it has the software producer's name instead of 'here'.